# Android Studio - Edit files visible in project view

Tags: android-studio

How can I edit the files that are visible under the "project" window with a certain view selected? E.g. I want to make my `versions.properties` file visible under the Gradle Scripts tab in the Android view. Is that possible?

*Note: I am using Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 with new UI.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a "versions.properties" file in your project. You can list items in the terminal or open the file explorer.

- To view all files, including "versions.properties," in the project tree, switch to Project view in Android view and double-click the file.

[image]

- To open "versions.properties," use the shortcut cmd/ctrl + shift + O and type "versions.

[image]